# To exemplify in the beginning of a sentence

Tags: example

I have read many discussions about this but couldn’t find an answer. Is it wrong to start a sentence with “to exemplify” or “to illustrate?” For example,”To exemplify, yesterday I was walking, and this happened.”

Comment: They're introductory elements in this usage. People probably wouldn't object to 'For example, yesterday I ...'. Or to  'If I might explain ... yesterday, ...'. Using a colon instead of a comma might appease some (colons have almost magical properties in licensing what follows), but this is a rather dated device. It might well be that this is an example of divided usage: some proficient native speakers will say it's totally acceptable, and others won't. FWIW, I'm happy with these in all but the most formal contexts (and would probably use a dash).

Comment: What was the gist of these discussions?